# What is the correct syntax to update a SQL Server table where the column has a data value of money

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use a simple `UPDATE` statement in T-SQL but running into an error.

The statement is

```
UPDATE PRODUCT
SET PURCHASE_COST = '20:00'
WHERE PROD_ID = 'PROD1001';
```

Bu I am getting the following error when executing it

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

`PURCHASE_COST` column has a data value of `money`.

So the question is how will I write the statement reflect money value and not a char value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `20:00` is not a numeric value. Perhaps you mean `20.00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE PRODUCT
SET PURCHASE_COST = 20.00 -- or simply 20
WHERE PROD_ID = 'PROD1001';
```

Also, `'20:00'` doesn't resemble money at all.

Comment: yes you are correct - just did not notice that simple error at all